# Why should I not use smart pointers?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

The question may seem a bit basic, but what are downsides of smart pointers besides performance? And should I always use them for non-performance-critical code?

EDIT: I use Visual Studio 2013 RC and C++11

Comment: Why do you think that, and what C++ standard is your compiler supporting (C++11 or something older)?

Comment: There are plenty of smart pointers that have no overhead whatsoever over using raw pointers. There are plenty of uses for raw pointers that are not incorrect. Also, it is often possible to avoid pointers altogether.

Comment: Before dismissing them even for performance critical paths, benchmark them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For e.g. a `unique_ptr`, there is unlikely to be any performance downside with any reasonable optimizing compiler.  For `shared_ptr` you have potentially an extra heap alloc -- something you can solve with `make_shared`, and there's the cost of maintaining a refcount, but consider that if you are rolling your own tracking or lifetime management mechanisms you may be taking this kind of overhead as well.  See [GotW #89](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/28/gotw-89-smart-pointers/) for more discussion of this.

Re "should I always use them", Sean Parent expounds on this (and some subtleties) in the GoingNative 2013 talk [C++ Seasoning](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Cpp-Seasoning) -- his third goal is "no raw pointers", and he gives a number of examples.  At one point he puts forth that shared_ptr-to-non-const is nearly equivalent to global variables...  It's worth watching this.  The [C++ Seasoning slides](https://github.com/sean-parent/sean-parent.github.com/wiki/Papers-and-Presentations) are available, but I'd recommend watching it.

Generally speaking, each smart pointer is going to have tradeoffs, just as raw pointers have tradeoffs.  It's going to be up to you to evaluate the situation and the tradeoffs and make a choice.  And it seems that there are enough well-vetted smart pointer variants to match many if not most situations these days, especially with the refinements in C++11 and C++14.

Answer (score 3):

I always use smart pointers to hold resources, even though the "smart" pointer may not be that smart, e.g., when using a `std::unique_ptr<T>` or `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`. When using pointers to model non-owning links or when passing non-owning pointers around I'm using raw pointers as they are the correct abstraction for this job and don't interfere with any choice made about how the object is owned.